# File upload size is not even 2MB in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload image to the some folder but only image having size less than 20Kb are only being uploaded. I am not able to upload even file upto 2Mb as it is by default in php.ini file. I have changes the values for

```
upload_max_filesize=40M 
post_max_size=40M
```

I dont know what the problem is. I am using a Xammp server

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php"); 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['subm']))
{
  extract($_POST);
  $_SESSION['artsubmit_error'] = "";
  $title1 =  $_POST['title'];
  $intro1 = $_POST['intro'];
  $descr1 = $_POST['descr'];

 $imgname= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 $artid = "".$_SESSION['logged_user_email']."";

 $allowedExts = array("GIF", "JPEG", "JPG", "PNG");
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);
 echo "$extension";
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {

    if(!is_dir("Article/".$artid.""))
     {  mkdir("Article/".$artid.""); }
     mkdir("Article/".$artid."/".$title1.""); 
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"article/".$artid."/".$title1."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."");
  }
  else
  {
    print "<br> ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."";print "<br>";
    print "<h2>Invalid image. File should be less than 2MB <h2>";
    header( "refresh: 2;url=articlestore.php" ); exit;
  }

  $parag = nl2br("$descr1");
  $query = "insert into article values('','$userid','$title1','$intro1','$parag','$imgname',NOW())";
  mysql_query($query) or die("unsucessfull");

  $_SESSION['artsubmit_error'] = "Article submitted. Post another";
  header("Location: articlestore.php" );exit; 
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Return the error 
`$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"article/".$artid."/".$title1."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."");
if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
}`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. I just changed

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
```

To

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","GIF","JPEG","JPG","PNG");
```

now its working fine for all type of images and even size greater than 2MB